# My c code for implementing ls, doesn't work on mac

Tags: c, macos

I'm facing a strange problem, last night I was doing my homework for implementing `ls` on my `linux`, the code works fine there, now when I test it on imac, it doesn't work. It only reads the current directory, it doesn't include subdirectories.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GREEN "\x1b[32m"
#define BLUE "\x1b[34m"
#define WHITE "\x1b[37m"

void Usage() {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: exec [OPTION]... [DIR]...\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "List DIR's (directory) contents\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\nOptions\n-R\tlist subdirectories recursively\n");
    return;
}

void RecDir(char * path, int flag) {
    DIR * dp = opendir(path);
    if(!dp) {
        perror(path);
        return;
    }
    struct dirent * ep;
    char newdir[512];
    printf(BLUE "\n%s :\n" WHITE, path);
    while((ep = readdir(dp)))
        if(strncmp(ep->d_name, ".", 1))
            printf(GREEN "\t%s" WHITE, ep->d_name);
    closedir(dp);
    dp = opendir(path);
    while((ep = readdir(dp))) if(strncmp(ep->d_name, ".", 1)) {
        if(flag && ep->d_type == 4) {
            sprintf(newdir, "%s/%s", path, ep->d_name);
            RecDir(newdir, 1);
        }
    }
    closedir(dp);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    switch(argc) {
    case 2:
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-R") == 0) 
            Usage();
        else 
            RecDir(argv[1], 0);
        break;
        case 3:
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-R") == 0) 
            RecDir(argv[2], 1);
        else 
            Usage();
        break;
        default: 
            Usage();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `DT_DIR` not `4`, but I don't think that's your problem.  Looks like mac defines it as 4.

Comment: Why are you checking the first character of the filename for "."?

Comment: your flag is always `0` as I checked, so it's not calling the `RecDir()` function.

Comment: @rrauenza I have changed the code to `strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0`

Comment: Oh, I forgot `strcmp` is negative logic.

Comment: @Bhansa I have removed the `flag` completely and still doesn't work. `if(ep->d_type == DT_DIR)`

Comment: Add some printfs and show what the `d_type` is of the files you're skipping.

Comment: FYI: `newdir[...]` should be `newdir[PATH_MAX]` and you should be using `snprintf` not `sprintf`.

Comment: Curious; the code works for me on Mac OS X 10.11.5.  It screws up my prompt colour, but apart from that, running `./rd19 -R BinarySearch` (where `BinarySearch` is a directory with a variety of binary search programs, and various `.dSYM` subdirectories, and it recursed OK.

Comment: OP should define his colors as `""` until this is figured out.  And add debug output of the filename/d_type.

Comment: Guys it works, with `stat` and `IS_ISDIR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it's another operating system, you first need to confirm that `d_type` holds the value that you think it does. In the first loop, as debug, print out `d_type` as well as the name.

> Note that in the second loop, you go through an awful lot of trouble scanning the directory a second time to recurse into subdirectories - and then at the last second decide not to if `flag` is `0`. Why not pre-test `flag` for `0` and simply not do the whole open-the-directory-again thing?

Comment: my `ep->d_type` is `0` for everything including `directories`.

Comment: Well; that's your problem. You'll need to do a `stat`. Note that the documentation for `d_type` warns that this might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The flag variable was always `0` so i changed it while calling the `RecDir()` function so that it will go into the if block:

```
if(flag && ep->d_type == 4) {
            sprintf(newdir, "%s/%s", path, ep->d_name);
            printf("here:  %s\n",ep->d_name);
            RecDir(newdir, 1);
        }
```

and be able to call `RecDir()` function recursively.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GREEN "\x1b[32m"
#define BLUE "\x1b[34m"
#define WHITE "\x1b[37m"

void Usage() {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: exec [OPTION]... [DIR]...\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "List DIR's (directory) contents\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\nOptions\n-R\tlist subdirectories recursively\n");
    return;
}

void RecDir(char * path, int flag) {
    DIR * dp = opendir(path);
    if(!dp) {
        perror(path);
        return;
    }
    struct dirent * ep;
    char newdir[512];
    printf(BLUE "\n%s :\n" WHITE, path);
    while((ep = readdir(dp)))
        if(strncmp(ep->d_name, ".", 1))
            printf(GREEN "\t%s" WHITE, ep->d_name);
    closedir(dp);
    dp = opendir(path);
    while((ep = readdir(dp))) if(strncmp(ep->d_name, ".", 1)) {
        //printf("In While %d\n",flag);
        if(flag && ep->d_type == 4) {
            sprintf(newdir, "%s/%s", path, ep->d_name);
            printf("here:  %s\n",ep->d_name);
            RecDir(newdir, 1);
        }
    }
    closedir(dp);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    switch(argc) {
    case 2:
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-R") == 0) 
            Usage();
        else 
            //supplied flag=1 instead of 0, explained above.
            RecDir(argv[1], 1);
        break;
        case 3: 
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-R") == 0) {
            RecDir(argv[2], 1);
        }
        else 
            Usage();
        break;
        default: 
            Usage();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output for all subdirectories]

Comment: Bhansa, do you have any comments on the code (in english language, not in C)? What was changed? What was wrong in original code?

Comment: @Bhansa this's strange, it doesn't work on my school iMac.

Comment: ...just to eliminate this, @TenTenPeter, make your colors empty strings for the moment.  Just in case you're have tty issues.

Comment: @Bhansa I have just printed `ep->d_type` and it displays `0` for everything including `directories`.

Comment: printing `ep->d_dtype` 8 out of the `if` block.